# '90s anime movie about a girl who was created by the villain using the DNA of the hero

Tags: story-identification, anime

I rented this dubbed (VHS) movie in the late '90s. It was a movie and not a series, although it had the feel that it was the big movie ending to a series.

There was a girl who was created by the villain using the DNA of the hero and either herself or one of his close friends. She got his DNA through some kind of portal thing and used a single hair. I kind of think the villain also had demon wings? There was some other realm thing where she was at, that much I remember.

The daughter, who was a fully grown woman, showed up to the house where the hero and a few girls lived. The hero was a brunet man. I remember specifically there was a scene with a pool or hot tub and she said,

> "Daddy!"

Obviously everybody freaked out, most specifically the hero. DNA stuff was done and they confirmed he was indeed her father. Later on in the film there's a big battle against the villain and the heroes win but the daughter is killed and turns into a gem.  I think the hero is forced to kill her, actually. The hero then takes the gem and incubates it in this lab he and his team have on their premises to grow the girl again, only this time to be a child and raise her to be good and without the evil influences of the villain. It ends with them all celebrating Christmas.

I've been trying to find this film for YEARS now and can't find it. I've searched so many lists and tried "soul gem clone", "anime movie where a girl is created by the villain using the DNA of the hero", "anime with soul gems," and even the more vague "anime with clones."

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? And when you say "hero," what kind of hero are we talking about? Did they have a costume or armour? Powers? Weapons? Is there any famous character that this hero was similar to?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.